# Difference between regex repeater and submatch recur

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone explain to me the differences between these two regex approaches:

```
/(\d)\1/
/(\d){2,}/
```

As far as I can see they both match for at least one recurrence of a subexpression. If they, in fact, do the same thing, are there any performance issues that distinguish them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they don't do the same

```
/(\d)\1/
```

matches

> 11 and 22 and 33

With the brackets you put the matched digit in a capture group and access that variable with `\1`, so you match two equal digits in a row.

while

```
/(\d){2,}/
```

matches

> 12 and 22 and 123456789 and 22222222

Here you say match two or more (`{2,}`) digits in a row. This can be different digits.

Answer (score 4):

- `/(\d)\1/` - Match a digit, capture it in group 1, and then match the **same digit** again, using a [back references](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#usebackrefinregex).
- `/(\d){2,}/` - Match 2 digits or more. The last digit will be captured in a group. Each digit is matched independently, they don't have to be the same.